# Add a question search to Area 51

Tags: feature-request, search, area-51

The more popular proposals on Area 51 have quite a lot of questions.  Many of them also have a lot of duplicated (or very similar questions).

It's possible that I am simply blind, but I could not find any way to search for an existing question.  I can search for *proposals* containing a keyword, but not for questions within a proposal.  When there are already 100 questions, that makes it difficult to figure out if my super-awesome question idea has already been tried (and perhaps rejected).

I know what some people are going to say - 50 questions is too many, people should be deleting, people shouldn't be submitting so many, we don't need to pile on, etc.  I get that you guys didn't plan to have this many questions, but that's what happened; the more popular a proposal becomes, the more questions it's going to have, period.  Just because a proposal has 80 questions doesn't mean that any of them are better than the one I want to submit (hypothetically speaking - I don't actually have any to submit at this moment).

So can we have a simple search?  It doesn't even need to be a search, given the format of Area 51, it can just be a *filter*, like the proposal search.  I think that this would help to reduce the number of duplicated/similar questions proposed.  Even if it only eliminates a small handful, every little bit helps when it comes to improving the signal-to-noise ratio there.